# Heroku slow with DB updates

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres

I am having issues with my heroku rails  app , which is not retrieving the recently updated DB values properly.

And by recently I mean more than an hour!

If I log into heroku console and verify the values in the DB, I can see the latest records. 
This particularly happen if the updates are through ActiveAdmin.

Note: I get stale data only in the views even if I restart heroku instance.

- What could be the problem ?
- Does heroku have a DB cache that I can bounce?
- Any other suggestions I can try ?

  Addons:        heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
                 newrelic:wayne
                 papertrail:choklad
  Region:        us
  Repo Size:     14M
  Slug Size:     105M
  Stack:         cedar

Comment: Guesses: You're reading rows from a lagging replica, or you're not actually committing the transactions when you do them, only much later when new work comes in.

Comment: Thanks Craig 
There are no replicas. Just one free instance. 
Also the transactions are committed , since I can see the values updated in the DB.

Comment: [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies). But I think ActiveAdmin is more likely.